# Merge features in same feature class on same attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, contour

I have a feature class of lake contours. This feature class is the result of multiple lakes' contour data being appended into my Contours feature class. I now have over 300,000 lines of contours, and I'm not done. This is slowing down processing and performane to an untenable degree. I need to merge these lines based on the fact that they're from the same lake, and they share a common contour value. So for example, I am currently going about this by 'select by attributes' attributes on my contours feature class, where `lake name = "" and contour = ""` then I just merge them in editor. But I want to be able to automate this with a script.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try the [dissolve](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) tool. This will merge polylines where their ends touch. Logically a contour from one lake would not be touching any other lake so there is no need to checking if they are the same name and elevation.

Comment: Thank you @Hornbydd! Something so simple, I imagined was going to be much more complicated. This did what I was hoping for. Thanks again :)